# jQuery find DIV inner value when click on radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What I'm trying to get is the immediate upper div value (Accounts Admin) when I'm clicking on a radio button.

Below is my HTML structure. Whenever I click on the admin or alan radio button give me the div inner text Accounts Admin.

How can get that value?

```html
<div class="display-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-1 ez-sub-heading mt-1">
    Accounts Admin
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div>
      <input
        id="admin"
        type="radio"
        value="admin"
        name="eng-name"
        class="eng-name userlist active"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div>
      <input
        id="alan"
        type="radio"
        value="alan"
        name="eng-name"
        class="eng-name userlist active"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying this way but I can't get the value.

$(this).parent().find(".ez-sub-heading").text()

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple blocks of this, I would change the html structure a bit so you have a wrapper around the complete block. With the `closest()` function you can find the first wrapper parent and then use `find()` to look for the header element.

You can use `trim()` to remove the whitespace caused by code indention.

```js
$('.userlist').on('click', (e) => {
  var text = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.wrapper').find('.ez-sub-heading').text();
  console.log(text.trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-flex flex-row wrapper">
  <div class="p-1 ez-sub-heading mt-1">
    Accounts Admin
  </div>
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div>
        <input id="admin" type="radio" value="admin" name="eng-name" class="eng-name userlist active">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div>
        <input id="alan" type="radio" value="alan" name="eng-name" class="eng-name userlist active">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="display-flex flex-row wrapper">
  <div class="p-1 ez-sub-heading mt-1">
    Accounts Admin 2
  </div>
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div>
        <input id="admin" type="radio" value="admin" name="eng-name2" class="eng-name userlist active">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div>
        <input id="alan" type="radio" value="alan" name="eng-name2" class="eng-name userlist active">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your HTML structure as it is, you need to find the closest (nearest parent) `.row` and then use `prevAll` to get the header row.

```
$(this).closest(".row").prevAll(".flex-row").first().text().trim()
```

```js
$("input.userlist").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest(".row").prevAll(".flex-row").first().text().trim())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-1 ez-sub-heading mt-1">
    Accounts Admin
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div>
      <input id="admin" type="radio" value="admin" name="eng-name" class="eng-name userlist active">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div>
      <input id="alan" type="radio" value="alan" name="eng-name" class="eng-name userlist active">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="display-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-1 ez-sub-heading mt-1">
    Second Header
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div>
      <input id="admin" type="radio" value="admin" name="eng-name" class="eng-name userlist active">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div>
      <input id="alan" type="radio" value="alan" name="eng-name" class="eng-name userlist active">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A small change to the HTML structure and adding some classes would make this much simpler (not included here as already suggested in the other answer).